# Is t correct to say "she lost her way home"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I remember I only say these to my daughter

"**She couldn't find her way home**"

"**She got lost in the forest**"

I have never said "**she lost her way home**" to her.

But today, she said "**she lost her way home**" to me.

Chatgpt said "**she lost her way home**" is a correct expression. But I feel it is not correct.

Comment: Who got lost? A  girl or your daughter? Did she use the pronoun "I" as in;  "I lost my way home" or was she referring to a different girl (perhaps in a story).

Comment: I would have thought the same - I wouldn't use _I lost my way_ immediately followed by the intended destination, but _I got lost on the way to XXX_. However, [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lost+my+way+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that the expression is becoming increasingly common.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, my daughter and I were playing a game and she pretended that her doll got lost and couldn't find the way home. So, "she" referred  to a certain girl in a game.

Comment: @Tom  "She lost her way home" is fine and perfectly grammatical. See here [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+lost+her+way+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Apparently some people are okay with *I lost my way home.* But many others (including me) would notice it as "unusual", so perhaps you should stick with your first instinct, and avoid using it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> *She couldn't find her way home*.
>
> *She lost her way home*.

These are both fine.

"Home" is best classified as a preposition. In your examples "home" means "to her place of residence", where the goal meaning of "home" is clear.

Comment: I'm OK with "She lost her way" or "She lost her way going home" but "She lost her way home" doesn't sound idiomatic to me. "to lose her way" is a phrasal verb meaning "to get lost"; "her way home" is a noun phrase meaning "a route taking her home". But it's weird to force them together like that.

Comment: @StuartF [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lost+her+way+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @BillJ: I don't like it either. Even in [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lost+on+my+way+home%2CI+lost+my+way+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10) it's much less common than *[I got] lost **on my way home***, and if you switch the corpus in that link to BrE, ***I lost my way home*** is too rare to even show on the chart.

Comment: If we can say "She lost her way", there's no reason why we can't also say "She lost her way home", meaning "She lost her way to her place of residence". I'd feel perfectly comfortable saying"I lost my way home".

Comment: Is "home" best classified as a preposition or a prepositional phrase? If it's a preposition, where's the complement?

Comment: @gotube either would be OK. "Home" is intransitive, i.e. it does not require a complement.

Comment: @BillJ Can you give me a link to a source that describes a noun like "home" as an intransitive preposition? I've found ones that describe actual prepositions like "in", "off" and "over" as such, but not nothing like "home".

Comment: @gotube We're not talking here of the noun use of "home", but of its prepositional classification, where no complement is required. Traditionally, the "home" in the OP's examples is analysed as an adverb, not a noun.